Query json column by date in postgres
i have a table in postgres named masters.



ID
Reference
CustomFieldsJson




1
John
[ { "ID": 17,"NumericValue": 1234},{ "ID":21,"DateValue":"2023-06-14T00:00:00Z"},{  "ID": 24, "BooleanValue": false }


2
Smith
[ { "ID": 17,"NumericValue": 1234},{ "ID":12,"DateValue":"2023-04-05T00:00:00Z"},{  "ID": 15, "ListItemValue": "india" }



CustomFieldsJson  column data type is jsonb.
I want to filter rows by custom_fields column key DateValue . For this i used json path expression as described in Postgres Documentation
select id,reference,custom_fields_json from master.masters
where custom_fields_json @? '$[*] ? (@.DateValue.datetime() > "2022-06-22T03:09:37Z".datetime())'

but filtering is not working. the query returns no rows. I think there is problem with dateformatting. in the documentation they showed example with "2015-08-12" date format

The problem is related to date formatting. The date format in your JSON data is ISO 8601 format, which should work well with PostgreSQL's JSON functions
Please try this one
SELECT id, reference, custom_fields_json 
FROM master.masters
WHERE custom_fields_json @? '$[*] ? (@.DateValue > "2022-06-22T03:09:37Z")';

Example:
Masters table:



id
reference
customfields




1
John
[{"ID": 17, "NumericValue": 1234}, {"ID": 21, "DateValue": "2023-06-14T00:00:00Z"}, {"ID": 24, "BooleanValue": false}]


2
Smith
[{"ID": 17, "NumericValue": 1234}, {"ID": 12, "DateValue": "2023-04-05T00:00:00Z"}, {"ID": 15, "ListItemValue": "india"}]



Query to select rows with DateValue greater than "2023-05-22T03:09:37Z"
SELECT id, reference, CustomFields 
FROM masters
WHERE CustomFields @? '$[*] ? (@.DateValue > "2023-05-22T03:09:37Z")';

Output:



id
reference
customfields




1
John
[{"ID": 17, "NumericValue": 1234}, {"ID": 21, "DateValue": "2023-06-14T00:00:00Z"}, {"ID": 24, "BooleanValue": false}]



fiddle

it has worked! thanks for the help.

@hafis you are most welcome. Best wishes.

I am afraid that comparing timestamp values formatted as text is generally a bad idea. Better cast/convert to timestamptz bedore comparison.

@Stefanov.sm i tried that, but type cast didnt work inside json path expression

@hafis You may try where exists (select from jsonb_array_elements(customfields) j where (j ->> 'DateValue')::timestamptz > '2022-06-22T03:09:37Z'::timestamptz) - with no json path expression.
